# JBoss not running on Eclipse Luna (Ubuntu 14)

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, jboss, application-server

I've just installed a tar.gz version of `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final` on my Ubuntu 14 pc. I was trying to run it from my Eclipse Luna IDE. I've downloaded JBoss AS Tools from Eclipse's `Help->Install new software` and then added a new **JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server**, which is using my `jdk1.7.0_60`.

But when I try to run it that's the error I receive:

```
Publishing to JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server has encountered a problem. 
An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server...".
org/eclipse/osgi/framework/internal/core/FrameworkProperties
```

I actually can't understand this error, even trying googling it, no results.
Can someone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: try to use a more recent jdk version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like it wants the `org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkProperties` class, but this is not part of the Eclipse Luna release, it was part of earlier releases.

So it looks like this version of JBoss is not compatible with Eclipse Luna.

Comment: The only thing I can say is :sadface: . Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Update JBoss Tools with the last release :
http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/luna/4.2.0.Final.html#update_site

Answer (score 0):

JBoss is not compatible with Eclipse Luna.